# Неправильно считаются тригонометрические функции

Tags: c#, математика

```
        double alfa;
        double z1, z2;

        Console.WriteLine("Введите a");
        alfa = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        alfa = alfa * ((double)180.0/ Math.PI);

        z1 = (Math.Sin((double)2.0 * alfa) + Math.Sin((double)5.0 * alfa) - Math.Sin((double)3.0 * alfa)) / (Math.Cos(alfa) - Math.Cos((double)3.0 * alfa) + Math.Cos((double)5.0 * alfa));

        z2 = Math.Tan((double)3.0 * alfa);

        Console.WriteLine("z1 = " + z1);
        Console.WriteLine("z2 = " + z2);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

По условию задачи, z1 и z2 должны совпадать, но по факту они различаются. Где здесь может ошибка? На картинке задание номер 4
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очевидно, что ошибка в вашей формуле. распишите ее на бумаге в виде тригонометрического уравнения, и все должно стать ясно

Comment: @МаксЖуков не могу найти ошибку

Comment: `(sin(2a)+sin(5a)-sin(3a)) / (cos(a)-cos(3a)+cos(5a)) == tg(3a)`? Вы уверены в этом? На тангенс не похоже: [ссылка](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sin%282a%29%2Bsin%285a%29-sin%283a%29%29+%2F+%28cos%28a%29-cos%283a%29%2Bcos%285a%29%29)

Comment: Неправильно считаться тригонометрические функции не могут, с поправкой, они считаются правильно до определенной точности епсилон, для епсилон < 0.001  как минимум.

Comment: при простой подстановке alfa = 30 получается 0.36 / 0 = infinity, что с натяжкой можно принять за тождество :)

Comment: Ошибки у вас нету. Они правда различаются. Либо у вас другое задание, либо у вас ошибка в методичке.

Comment: У вас неправильно считается альфа, для получения радиан нужно умножить на Пи, делить на 180, но к различию результатов это не имеет отношения.

Comment: Точно...  `rad = alpha * 2 * PI / 360 = alpha * PI / 180`  но к различию результатов это не имеет отношения... корме случая... если функции ведут себя одинаково на малом промежутке.